# How avoid relative paths (../../../../../) in import statement in the client side (React)

Tags: phoenix-framework, brunch, es6-modules

I'm using Elixir Phoenix framework with Brunch as build tool.

I know that Webpack has the "resolve" feature, can I do similar thing in my environment?

Do you have any other clean solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi @giraffe_head, any progress with this? I'm also facing this problem...

Comment: @GPrimola No... but if you are starting a project today, consider using webpack instead of brunch

Answer (score 0):

You can just use absolute paths like: `/components/forum/Post`.

Comment: what is the root /, is it configurable?